# set a radio button selected by defualt in Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: view, asp.net-core-mvc, radio-button

I can not select a default option for my radio buttons in my view.

I have tried:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.Before, false, new { @checked = true }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.Before, false, new { @class = "checked" })
```

and many other ways - but none of them is working!
and also I like to make it required. How can I make it selected and required?

I am using .NET Core 5.

Comment: Only if the value of the Before is same as your second parameter value(false in your code),it will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make it selected:

The radio button will be checked if the value of property in the model is equal to the second argument we pass in to RadioButtonFor method.

So, in your case if you set Before property to false, then the radio button will be checked. I guess the right way would be set the value of Before to true and pass true as second argument value.

To make it require:
Decorate the Property with "**System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute**" attribute which makes the property required. Now you can check this.ModelState.IsValid in the post method and return this.Page().

> Note: The page can be validated at client side if you use
> jquery-validation library.
>
> In case of bool types they will always have either true or false so
> the model will always be valid even user won't select it. In this case
> use nullable bool instead of bool.

```
[BindProperty]
[Required]
public bool? Before{ get; set; }
```

In the get method

```
this.Before = true;
```

In the view

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.Before, true)
```

Please let me know if that works.

Comment: this is for a bit value from DB so the full code is
@Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.PatchBefore, false) No
@Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.PatchBefore, true) Yes
but none of them is checked. do u think the value of the second parameter (false/true) would override by the value of PatchBefore? because this is null at first. and in fact, I like client-side validation and I am already using jquery-validation for some inputs.

Comment: Passing null to second parameter will throw an exception. So, if you want to have @Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.PatchBefore, false) and select this radio button then set PatchBefore to false (if null in DB) before returning the model to view.